# Passing props to route component through this.$router.push in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

Configuration of router :

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/' , redirect: '/login'},
    { path: '/chat', component: MyChat,props: true},
    { path: '/login', component: MyLogin},
  ]
```

Chat component with props :

```
export default {
    name: "MyChat",
    props:{
      avatar_url : {
        type: String,
      }
    }
```

The router push to pass props :

```
 this.$router.push({path:'/chat',props: {avatar_url: 'rrrrrrr'}});
```

When I'm passing props directly in routes array it does work :

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/' , redirect: '/login'},
    { path: '/chat', component: MyChat,props: {avatar_url: 'myurl'}},
    { path: '/login', component: MyLogin},
  ]
```

But when I try to pass props in the this.$router.push it doesn't , if anyone has an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean mode only [passes on route params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode), so `avatar_url` would have to be part of the url, something like:

```
{ path: '/chat/:avatar_url', component: MyChat, props: true},
```

In Vue 2, I remember you could still get other props from the route in [function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode):

```
{
  path: '/chat',
  component: MyChat,
  props: route => ({ avatar_url: route.props.avatar_url })
},
```

but I am not sure if that still works in Vue 3.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work

Comment: I find anither solution as you said , instead of passing props i'm passing parameters in url